# How do I assert that the code is running in the main thread?

Tags: c#

This doesn't work:

```
Debug.Assert(Thread.CurrentThread.Name == "Main Thread"); //doesn't work
                     //name is null despite name
                     //in debugger being "Main Thread"
```

This does work:

```
Debug.Assert(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == 1);
```

But I was just wondering:

- a) Is `ManagedThreadId` guaranteed to be `1` for the Main Thread?
- b) Is there a better way of doing this? Via Attribute would be neatest I feed.

I'm working on a Silverlight project, I haven't tagged as such as I don't know it's relevant, but please comment if you belive there is a difference between Silverlight and other .net runtimes.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "Main Thread"? The first to be created by the runtime?

Comment: Try out following thread name - `"UI Thread"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374451/how-to-tell-if-a-thread-is-the-main-thread-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Cicada Probably, it's the name shown in the debugger in the Threads window. It might say something else in French.

Comment: @sll No, `Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `entry` method of an application -

```
static int mainThreadId;

// In Main method:
mainThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

// If called in the non main thread, will return false;
public static bool IsMainThread
{
    get
    {
       return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                                                == mainThreadId;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is "copied" from answer given by Zach Johnson here (link below) 2 years before your answer-date! What a "coincidence". Check it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374451/how-to-tell-if-a-thread-is-the-main-thread-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Thread.CurrentThread.Name only works if the name was set.  My guess is the debugger provides a default name. Can you set the name of the thread (at creation, or as soon as you hit main, perhaps)?  This way you can check the assertion.

Something like:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Check whether the thread has previously been named 
    // to avoid a possible InvalidOperationException. 
    if(Thread.CurrentThread.Name == null)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "MainThread";
    }
}
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.name.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the [`IsBackground`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property.

This might not be a perfect solution as other threads can run as foreground threads, but it might be sufficient enough.

Comment: From the documentation on MSDN it appears threads other than the main thread could have the 'IsBackground' set to false: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground.aspx)